# varnish backend VCC-compiler failed

Tags: reverse-proxy, varnish

i want to add an varnish proxy infront of my SX server i have two droplets ip:192.168.0.100 ip: 192.168.0.101 both works in lan but while restarting varnish shows a compile error

nano /etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
# define our first nginx server
backend nginx01 {
    .host = "192.168.0.100";
    .port = "80";
}

# define our second nginx server
backend nginx02 {
    .host = "192.168.0.101";
    .port = "80";
}

# configure the load balancer
director nginx round-robin {
    { .backend = nginx01; }
    { .backend = nginx02; }
}

# When a request is made set the backend to the round-robin director named nginx
sub vcl_recv {
    set req.backend = nginx;
}
```

while restarting varnish shows an error

```
root@Sproxy:~# service varnish restart
Message from VCC-compiler:

directors are now in directors VMOD.
('input' Line 30 Pos 1)
director nginx round-robin {
########--------------------

Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2

VCL compilation failed
 * Syntax check failed, not restarting
```

Comment: Which Varnish are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Despite the example given by @Redithion, the right configuration for Varnish 4.0 seems to be :

```
vcl 4.0;

import directors;

backend nginx01 {
    .host = "192.168.0.100";
    .port = "80";
}

backend nginx02 {
    .host = "192.168.0.101";
    .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_init {
    new nginx = directors.round_robin();
    nginx.add_backend(nginx01);
    nginx.add_backend(nginx02);
}

sub vcl_recv {
    set req.backend_hint = nginx.backend();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Varnish 4.0. In this version directors has been [moved to VMODs](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/whats-new/upgrading.html)

Here is an example based in what I got from [here](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleDirector):

```
vcl 4.0;

# define first nginx server
backend nginx01 {
    .host = "192.168.0.100";
    .port = "80";
}

# define second nginx server
backend nginx02 {
    .host = "192.168.0.101";
    .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_init {
    new cluster1 = directors.round_robin();
    cluster1.add_backend(nginx01, 1.0);
    cluster1.add_backend(nginx02, 1.0);
}

sub vcl_recv {
    set req.backend_hint = cluster1.backend();
}
```

**Tip:** Don't forget the "vcl 4.0;" statement!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got the compile error because I had following codein my default.vcl file for Magento2.

```
# To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
if (req.http./* {{ ssl_offloaded_header }} */) {
    hash_data(req.http./* {{ ssl_offloaded_header }} */);
}
```

which I had to replace with

```
# To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
if (req.http.ssl_offloaded_header) {
    hash_data(req.http.ssl_offloaded_header);
}
```